# cxf https chunking off not working , I have tried through config and explicitly in java

Tags: cxf, chunked-encoding, chunking, cxf-client

I am trying to turn off chunking for my java web application. We use apache cxf and are hitting a soap service.

1. I changed the conduit setting in the config file

```
<http-conf:conduit 
name="*.http-conduit">
<http-conf:client
ConnectionTimeout="2000"
ReceiveTimeout="60000"
MaxRetransmits="2"
ChunkingThreshold="700000"
AllowChunking="false"/>
</http-conf:conduit>
```

2. Set it manually

```java
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit)client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(2000);
httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(60000);
httpClientPolicy.setMaxRetransmits(2);
httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

None of them work and any request above 4k I see transfer-encoding: chunked

Another side question: Is there a different setting for HTTPS and HTTP in cxf?